# Removing the edge margin of an element "li"

Tags: html, css, padding, margin, html-lists

I am with [this](http://jsfiddle.net/Ridermansb/5jJg3/15/) HTML and it all elements **`li.gradient-top`** seem to have an edge right

I've checked on several debugger tools but do not know why he's putting the margin between an `li` element and another `li`.

How to remove this margin?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That is not margin but a space character.  Since these are inline elements, whitespace is displayed between them if it exists in the markup.  Remove the whitespace from the html.  Eg:

```
    <li>...</li>
    <li>...</li>
```

Becomes:

```
    <li>...</li><li>...</li>
```

If you don't want to change the markup, you can try applying `float: left` to the `<li>` elements.

Comment: Why this happens, just the fact of placing elements side by side just removes the white space. Very strange.